# Оправдано ли присутствие тире в данном контексте?

Tags: пунктуация

> Так, мы влюбились в небольшой старинный городок, ровесник
>   Санкт-Петербурга – Парати, что означает часть земли, подаренная тебе
>   Богом.

Comment: Не скажу насчёт тире, но первая запятая выглядит подозрительно. Соответствующий контекст можно представить, конечно, но...

Comment: Это я её поставила, она вызвана предыдущими влюблениями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь, как мне кажется, возможны два варианта:

Так, мы влюбились в небольшой старинный городок, **ровесник Санкт-Петербурга**, – Парати, что означает часть земли, подаренная тебе Богом.

Так, мы влюбились в небольшой старинный городок, **ровесник Санкт-Петербурга,** Парати, что означает часть земли, подаренная тебе Богом.

Сравнить:

Верстах в пятнадцати от моего имения живет один мне знакомый человек, **молодой помещик, гвардейский офицер в отставке,** Аркадий Павлыч Пеночкин.

По ночам часто плакал во сне пес, **по прозванию Фунтик**, – маленькая рыжая такса (Пауст.).

Answer (score 1):

Обособленное приложение, стоящее в конце предложения отделяется тире. Перед таким приложением можно встсвть слово "а именно".

Так, мы влюбились в небольшой старинный городок, ровесник Санкт-Петербурга **(а именно)** – Парати, что означает часть земли, подаренная тебе Богом.

Comment: Серж, Вы и Жасмин правы, автору будут понятны оба ваших ответа, и мучаюсь, кому вручить ЛОшку... Простите, ответ Жасмин... "вариативнее". Но мне по душе Ваше тире без предшествующей запятой. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

*Так мы влюбились в небольшой старинный городок (ровесник Санкт-Петербурга) с именем Парати, которое означает — часть земли, подаренная тебе Богом.*

Два подряд идущих названия городов даже с паузой воспринимается с трудом, и от этой тесноты нужно уйти. Во-вторых, городок (Парати) сам по себе означать ничего не может, как только «городок»; означает же слово. Третье, и это вопрос: это короткое слово действительно может быть выражено только пятью другими? Я бы сократил до «земля, подаренная Богом».